# Run function on all cells in table column with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table element defined below as `$table`. I am trying to run a function on every cell a specific column that is defined by a specific table heading - `qc_statusTh`. I have found the index of that table heading (`qc_statusColumnIndex`) and have been able to grab the next table cell in that column - `qc_statusCell`.

However, I am not able to loop through the table cells and run a function on each table cell in that column.

Here is the JavaScript code I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("table.tables.list");

  if ($table.length > 0) {
    var qc_statusTh = $("th.headersub:contains('qc_status')");
    var qc_statusColumnIndex = $(qc_statusTh).index();
    var qc_statusCell = $($table).find("td").eq(qc_statusColumnIndex);

    // this does not work. this only replaces the first cell
    // in the row after qc_statusTh with "TESTING"

    $(qc_statusCell).each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith("TESTING");
    });

  }

});
```

How can I edit this code to loop through each cell in the table that has an equal index to `qc_statusColumnIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, you really want to iterate (using `each`) over the rows of the table, not the cells. If you do that, you can then grab the *nth* `td` element from each row and apply your transformation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("table.tables.list");

  if ($table.length > 0) {
    var qc_statusTh = $("th.headersub:contains('qc_status')");
    var qc_statusColumnIndex = $(qc_statusTh).index();
    
    var qc_rows = $($table).find('tr');

    $(qc_rows).each(function() {
      $(this).find('td').eq(qc_statusColumnIndex).replaceWith("TESTING");
    });

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="tables list">
  <thead>
    <th class="headersub">qc_example</th>
    <th class="headersub">qc_status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Error</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```